# Changing the color of NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

What is the best way to change the color of NSProgressIndicator, is there an easier way than just to subclass it and then draw the whole component by myself?

Basically what I want to do is to have a similar component but with the ability to change the color of the bar.

I tried to google this but all the questions were quite outdated and didn't really concern the 10.10 OS X version that I am working on. Also checked cocoa controls and did only find 1 component that was for outdated OS X version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Quartz filters (e.g. hue adjust) for this directly in Interface Builder. This works better than expected.

[image: NSProgressIndicator]

It's in the Effects Inspector. Under "Content Filters" you can add "Hue Adjust"

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to modify this programmatically?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is done in Interface Builder?

Comment: I'm not clear on how to actually set the colour after adding "hue adjust" to the content filters.

Comment: A better way to do this is to first apply the Color Monochrome filter with 50% gray, then the Sepia Tone filter (to arrive at a predictable color), and then the Hue Adjust filter to get the color you want.

Comment: I suggest adding the false color content filter instead of hue adjust

Comment: But how is this implemented programmatically in your code to implement the Hue Adjust, say at 75% of the progress?

Answer (score 1):

Use "CIFalseColor" filter to get white color and more.

```
let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor")!
colorFilter.setDefaults()
colorFilter.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
colorFilter.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")
proggressBar?.contentFilters = [colorFilter]
```

Comment: How do you set the values for color1 and color2 ?

Comment: let color1 = NSColor(red: 99.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)  and similarly for color 2

Comment: Okay, I've been messing around with this for a while.  I have defined inputColor0 and inputColor1 through the IB as False Color Content Filter.  How would I go about flipping/inverting the two colors.  Say my progressBar reaches a certain point, inputColor1 would then become the color of the progressBar.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to change de Hue as seen in most answers, but I was getting a lot of issues to get the right specific color I wanted.

What did worked for me, and seems to be the most direct way to get a specific color, was using the [CIColorMonochrome](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicolormonochrome) filter, where You can set any RGB color you want:

[image]

```swift
let myCustomColor = CIColor(red: 10, green: 10, blue: 10)
if let colorMonochrome = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMonochrome", parameters: [kCIInputColorKey: myCustomColor]) {
    progressIndicator.contentFilters.append(colorMonochrome)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from [KamyFC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456092/2439941) I found out that `CIColor` was required for the filter named "CIFalseColor".

Here is the Objective-C solution to make the progress bar whatever `NSColor`, in this example orange.
Don't forget to add `@import Quartz;` to your file.

```
// Create color:
CIColor *color = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[NSColor orangeColor]];

// Create filter:
CIFilter *colorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor"
                             withInputParameters:@{@"inputColor0" : color,
                                                   @"inputColor1" : color}];

// Assign to bar:
_progressBar.contentFilters = @[colorFilter];
```

Answer (score 0):

To change color of `NSProgressIndicator` use [setControlTint:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProgressIndicator/setControlTint:) method. If you want to set custom color you have to draw such control manually. However, you should use the system color to keep this kind of control consistent across the system.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift the method name is `controlTint`.

```
progressIndicator = NSProgressIndicator(frame: .......
progressIndicator.controlTint = .blueControlTint
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use proggressBar.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantLight) // this is light or vibrantDark for "black" indictor

Answer (score 0):

Based on Paxos' answer on the Interface builder, this is how I was able to do it programmatically:

```
let progress = NSProgressIndicator()
progress.contentFilters = [CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust", parameters: ["inputAngle": 4])!]
```

This would turn the bar green.  I got this from looking at the Main.storyboard diff:

```
<progressIndicator maxValue="100" doubleValue="50" style="bar" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NIr-vo-obX">
  <rect key="frame" x="3" y="22" width="210" height="20"/>
+ <contentFilters>
+  <ciFilter name="CIHueAdjust">
+   <configuration>
+    <real key="inputAngle" value="4"/>
+    <null key="inputImage"/>
+   </configuration>
+  </ciFilter>
+ </contentFilters>
</progressIndicator>
```