# Tinting NSProgressIndicator to graphite is not effective

Tags: swift

I am trying to tint a progress bar in a macOS application written in Swift 3. After a bit of researching, I came to this:

```
convertProgress.controlTint = NSControlTint.graphiteControlTint
```

However, it doesn't seem to change the tint at all – the progress bar stays blue.

Comment: Take a look to this older answer in StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506002/changing-the-color-of-nsprogressindicator

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. I also wanted to the ability to change the tint programmatically, but forgot to add that in the question – so perhaps I'll ask another question

Comment: If you look at the answer of that question, you can see that you can do it programatically as well, using [setControlTint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprogressindicator#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProgressIndicator/setControlTint:), so you don't need to ask a new question.

Comment: It looks like the `setControlTint` method is deprecated. I don't see it in the linked documentation; am I missing anything?